# How to translate multiple parameters to a PHP conditional if statement

Tags: php

Let's say I have the following url: `example.php?grab=1,3&something=...`

`grab` has two values, how can I translate that to a conditional if statement. 
For example, if `count` is a variable and you want to calculate if `count` is equal to one of the `grab` values.

```
$grab = $_GET["grab"];

$count = 4;

if($count == $grab(values)) {
alert("True");
}
```

Comment: [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) your grab parameter and use [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) or use [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) and check for `!== false` (meaning it's in there)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its always going to be `,` that glues the values, just `explode` them, that turns them into an `array`. Then just use your resident array functions to check. In this example, `in_array`:

```
if(!empty($_GET['grab'])) {
    $grab = $_GET["grab"];
    $count = 4;
    $pieces = explode(',', $grab);
    if(in_array($count, $pieces)) {
        // do something here if found
    }
}
```

Sidenote: If you try to devise your url to be like this:

`example.php?grab[]=1&grab[]=3&something`

You wouldn't need to explode it at all. You can just get the values, and straight up use `in_array`.

The example above `grab` already returns it an array:

```
if(!empty($_GET['grab'])) {
    $grab = $_GET["grab"];
    $count = 4;
    if(in_array($count, $grab)) {
        // do something here if found
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Method#1: Reformat URL and Use PHP in_array()**

Why not reformat your url to something like this: `example.php?grab[]=1&grab[]=3&something=...` which automatically returns the `grab` value as an array in PHP?

And then do something like:

```
if(isset($_GET['grab']) && in_array(4, $_GET['grab'])) {
    // do something
}
```

**Method#2: Split String into Array and Use PHP in_array()**

If you do not wish to reformat your url, then simply split the string into an array using php's explode function and check if value exists, for example:

```
if(isset($_GET['grab'])) {
    $grab_array = explode(",", $_GET['grab'])
    if(in_array(4, $grab_array)) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

**Method#3: Use Regular Expressions**

You could also use regular expressions to check for a match.